# Apex trigger to insert attachment into custom object gives "Insert failed" error

Tags: apex, trigger, case

When my Salesforce receives e-mails it will create a Case for it. I want the attachments from that case to be copied to my custom object "Case_Attachment__c".

I created a Apex Trigger for this:

```
trigger CaseAttachmentTrigger on Attachment  (after insert) {
    List<Case_Attachment__c> cons = new List<Case_Attachment__c>();
    for(Attachment a :trigger.new){
        Case_Attachment__c c  = new Case_Attachment__c();
        c.name = a.name;
        c.Attachment__c = a.id;
        c.Case__c = a.parentId;
        cons.add(c);
    }
    insert cons;
}
```

However I get this error:

```
caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Case: id value of incorrect type: a1G25000000aL35EAE: [Case__c]

Trigger.CaseAttachmentTrigger: line 10, column 1
```

This is my custom fields:

- Attachment Attachment__c Text(100)
- Case Case__c Master-Detail(Case)
- View View__c Formula (Text) _c   Master-Detail(Case)

Comment: Are looking for attachment from the email to copied into your custom object ?  When you configured email-to-case , sales-force will be creating case and email received will be attached into case record.

Comment: NITHESH K: That is correct. I can see the attachment is being created to that emails, and that it has parent ID for the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is that the parent object of the `Attachment` looks like it is a custom object not a `Case` object.

You need to remember that your trigger will run for any `Attachment` added to *any* type of object so you should be *very* careful about the logic so that it is only applied where it is relevant. (Getting this wrong for an object that is used by many different apps in an org can mean that you break those apps not just your own app.)

For example:

```
trigger CaseAttachmentTrigger on Attachment (after insert) {
    List<Case_Attachment__c> cons = new List<Case_Attachment__c>();
    for(Attachment a : Trigger.new) {
        // Ignore Attachments added to any other type of object
        if (a.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {
            Case_Attachment__c c = new Case_Attachment__c(
                Name = a.Name,
                Attachment__c = String.abbreviate(a.Body, 100),
                Case__c = a.ParentId
            );
            cons.add(c);
        }
    }
    insert cons;
}
```

(It looks like `Case_Attachment__c.Attachment__c` is a text field not an Id field so I've changed that logic a bit too.)